# How can I link between jQuery v.3 tabs?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to use links inside the `.tab-content` divs to link to one of the other tabs, but the links don't work. These are not jQuery UI tabs.

The top tab `.tab-link` links work, of course, to switch in between tabs. Is it possible to link from the `.tab-content` of one tab and open another tab?

I.e. using `<a href="#case-story">link to tab</a>` in `.tab-content` to open the `<a href="#case-story" class="tab-link">` tab?

The HTML looks like this for each tab:

```
<ul class="accordion-tabs-minimal">

<li id="tab-overview" class="tab-header-and-content client-case__overview">
<a href="#overview" class="tab-link"><span class="title">Overview</span></a>

<div class="tab-content">
Example Link to other tab <a href="#case-story">Case Story</a>
</div>
</li>

<li id="tab-case-story" class="tab-header-and-content client-case__case_story">
<a href="#case-story" class="tab-link">
<span class="title">The Story</span>
</a>

<div class="tab-content">
lorem ipsum lorem      
</div>
</li>
```

This is the jQuery that enables the "tab" links to show/hide content; how do I also enable links in the body of the tabs - in `tab-content` - to also show/hide content?

```
$(function() {

  $('.accordion-tabs-minimal').each(function(index) {

    var tab = '';
    // Check, if there is a tab id in url.
    if (window.location.hash) {
      tab = $(this).find('li#tab-' + window.location.hash.substr(1));
    }

    if (tab.length) {
      tab.children('a').addClass('is-active').next().addClass('is-open').show();
    } else {
      if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
        $(this).children('li').first().children('a').addClass('is-active').next().addClass('is-open').show();
      }
    }
  });


  $('.accordion-tabs-minimal').on('click', 'li > a.tab-link', function(event) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var accordionTabs = $(this).closest('.accordion-tabs-minimal');
      accordionTabs.find('.is-open').removeClass('is-open').hide();

      $(this).next().toggleClass('is-open').toggle();
      accordionTabs.find('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
      $(this).addClass('is-active');

      if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
        window.location.hash = '#' + $(this).parent().attr('id').substr(4);
      }
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();

      if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $(this).removeClass('is-active');
        $(this).next().removeClass('is-open').hide();
      }
    }
  });

});;
```

**Complete markup and Javascript is in a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/r64nj6pL/39/**  Try the link in the "Overview" tab; it doesn't go to the "Case Story" tab.

Comment: The jsfiddle example works, without using jQuery-UI, so I don't see what the question is.

Comment: I'm trying to link between tabs. Try the link in the "Overview" tab; it doesn't go to the "Case Story" tab. For some reason, the tabs don't show in the fiddle when first loaded; different issue with the fiddle, but that doesn't matter to me in the fiddle.

Comment: "that seems to be required most of the time to link between tabs". The tabs are just divs, you can fairly easily write code to show and hide them if you want to. Just like you show and hide any other HTML element. Sure jQueryUI's tabs plugin makes it simple, but it's not _required_ in order to show/hide elements on a page.

Comment: @Archer what he is trying to say is click `Overview` then from the Overview **content** click > Link to next tab: `Case Story`

Comment: The tabs show/hide fine; I need to link between them.

Comment: Conceptually it's the same thing. Clicking the link needs to _cause_ the show/hide operation, just the same as clicking on the header (which is also a link, except the action which is triggered when you click it is controlled by some other JS code).

Comment: Ok, if it's the same thing: how do I get it to work? The existing function needs to be modified to handle tab body links as well as tab header links?

Comment: When the link is clicked, do the same thing as the code which controls the headers. The code in your fiddle already shows what happens when one of those links is clicked.

Comment: Ok, fiddle edited: https://jsfiddle.net/r64nj6pL/39/

Comment: so you've removed your previous code, now you need to handle your custom link being clicked on, and do something. or amend the selector in the existing click event (and/or the HTML of your custom link) so that it triggers for your link as well.

Comment: So I need the jQuery look for a link within the tab-content div as well as in the li accordion-tabs-minimal?

Comment: yes that's one way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just trigger the click event of the matching tab link?
Like this:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.accordion-tabs-minimal').each(function(index) {

    var tab = '';
    // Check, if there is a tab id in url.
    if (window.location.hash) {
      tab = $(this).find('li#tab-' + window.location.hash.substr(1));
    }

    if (tab.length) {
      tab.children('a').addClass('is-active').next().addClass('is-open').show();
    } else {
      if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
        $(this).children('li').first().children('a').addClass('is-active').next().addClass('is-open').show();
      }
    }
  });


  $('.accordion-tabs-minimal').on('click', 'li > a.tab-link', function(event) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('is-active')) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var accordionTabs = $(this).closest('.accordion-tabs-minimal');
      accordionTabs.find('.is-open').removeClass('is-open').hide();

      $(this).next().toggleClass('is-open').toggle();
      accordionTabs.find('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
      $(this).addClass('is-active');

      if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
        window.location.hash = '#' + $(this).parent().attr('id').substr(4);
      }
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();

      if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $(this).removeClass('is-active');
        $(this).next().removeClass('is-open').hide();
      }
    }
  });

});

  $('.accordion-tabs-minimal').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('tab-link')) { // make sure that user has not clicked on .tab-link itself
      var tablink = $('.accordion-tabs-minimal li > a.tab-link[href="'+$(this).attr('href')+'"]');
      if(tablink.length == 1) { // make sure current link matches a tab link
        event.preventDefault();
       tablink.click();
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.tab-content ul {
  margin: 15px 0;
  padding-left: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

.accordion-tabs-minimal .tab-header-and-content {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.accordion-tabs-minimal .tab-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
}

.accordion-tabs-minimal {
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 0;
}

.accordion-tabs-minimal::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.accordion-tabs-minimal .tab-link {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.accordion-tabs-minimal .tab-link::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.accordion-tabs-minimal .tab-link:hover,
.accordion-tabs-minimal .tab-link.is-active {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: #eaeaea;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- trying jQUery 3.3.1 -->

<ul class="accordion-tabs-minimal">

<li id="tab-overview" class="tab-header-and-content client-case__overview">
<a href="#overview" class="tab-link"><span class="title">Overview</span></a>

<div class="tab-content">Link to next tab: <a href="#case-story">Case Story</a></div>
</li>

<li id="tab-case-story" class="tab-header-and-content client-case__case_story">
<a href="#case-story" class="tab-link"><span class="title">Case Story</span></a>

<div class="tab-content">lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</div>
</li>

<li id="tab-timeline" class="tab-header-and-content client-case__timeline">
<a href="#timeline" class="tab-link"><span class="title">The Case</span></a>

<div class="tab-content">lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem<br /> ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum </div>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, that appears to work. Simple solution. I edited your answer to try jQuery 3.3.1 but someone needs to approve the edit.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Edit Approved. Btw, you may consider marking it as Accepted Answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will; I need to test it on the live version.

Comment: Doesn't work on the live site; no errors in the console. Any ideas what to check? Same jQuery library version.

Comment: 1. Check the css classnames, 2. Make sure the HTML structure is same as that you have used in this question / jsfiddle. If its different then some tweaking might be needed in `var tablink=` selector 3. How about adding some breakpoints and debugging the JS code. For Chrome you can find the steps @ https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: Works now; thanks! Must have been a glitch when the js was compressed or cached.